# Spf Records Prevent "Too Many MX Resource Records" and too many operators / remove duplicate actions

Tags: smtp, spf

we have setup SPF like below (ips changed for demo purposes)

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:188.166.200.10 ip4:178.62.229.10 ip6:2a03:b0c0:2:d0::30f:1003 
include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net -all
```

We are receiving a warning "Too Many MX Resource Records" and also it was reported that we have both: ps defined, a, mx and include statements.

Question: what is an optimal SPF record definition where we don't "over do it" ... with the goal to remove duplicate actions in this record

Rationale

- ip4 an ip6 records are from actual server
- a records should resolve to the same as ip4 an ip6 (so this is already unnecessary?)
- mx records should resolve to the same as the google spf include? This part is not clear to me - maybe here we a creating far too many lookups? If I look here then the _spf record resolves to many other ips too in he chain https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3a_spf.google.com&run=toolpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is a bit confusing – it doesn't sound like it's about your SPF, but about your MX records.

MX records designate your *inbound* mail servers, and do not necessarily correspond with the servers that can *send* for your domain, which is what SPF covers. For example, it's likely your web server can send mail for your domain, but it won't accept mail sent to it.

It does sound like you have too many MX records. Without knowing your domain I can't check that, but you shouldn't have more than about 5.

Aside from that, your SPF looks fine.

Comment: It’s the include statements that resolve to other underlying domains (just follow the google spf link for example) ...

Comment: So in this case: you could remove the mx statement?

Comment: The gmail ones are not too bad – you would have a maximum of 4 lookups to see all their IP ranges. The mailchimp one is a single lookup (though they are pretty clueless since it ends with `~all`). In all you're easily under the 10 limit, so I'm not sure why you would be getting any errors from this record. You should however put the literal `ip` mechanisms before the `a`, `mx`, and `include` ones as they are faster for receivers to evaluate. That said, `mx` records always have to be names, not IPs, so they will incur lookups, and if you have 5 (common for gmail) this may be taking you over.

Comment: You can always try it out – turn off DMARC rejection for SPF and remove the `mx` mechanism and see if you get any failures.

Comment: Yes thanks. So the ones that send the most email should go first and probably the ips. For the test: haha won’t do that on live but let me check the mx against the spf resolutions on op level later. Thx 